# Customized component in Spring Boot

Tags: components, customization

As we all know we have autoconfiguration in Spring Boot and it recognizes 3 layers in Component Scan. COntroller , service and Repository. However If I add extra layer say "transformation" layer ...is it possible?
Is there any examples of the same.

I have tried @Component and lazy loading to solve it . But I get Circular error or something.